# Help ethernet problem disappears when I restart or suspend my laptop

Tags: networking, suspend, laptop, ethernet

I would like you to help me. I had this problem that when I restart or suspend my laptop, the ethernet connection disappears completely. And what is available is the wifi when restarting the ethernet is enabled then restart is disabled is somewhat stressful and because the connection to ethernet is much faster.
I have a toshiba laptop brand A665-S6100X has a ssd intel of 256 and a hard drive 8gb ram ddr3 1333
It has happened to me also with ubuntu 16.04
It does not happen to me with windows when I had it installed but if here it could be
I hope you can help me.

Comment: Your question tells us about your SSD, your HDD, your RAM and your RAM speed but it doesn't tell us about your WiFi or Ethernet. Please open a terminal by pressing `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T` keys at the same time. Then type `sudo lshw -class network`. Using your mouse highlight the last line and pull the mouse up to highlight all text up to the command. Then right click with your mouse and select `copy`. Then edit your question above and right click with the mouse and select `paste` to put the terminal output into your question. Then highlight the newly inserted text in your question and click the `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
      *-network                 
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       producto: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:01:00.0
       nombre lógico: enp1s0
       versión: 05
       serie: b8:70:f4:57:26:e1
       tamaño: 100Mbit/s
       capacidad: 100Mbit/s
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuración: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw ip=192.168.1.103 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       recursos: irq:33 ioport:e000(size=256) memoria:f0004000-f0004fff memoria:f0000000-f0003fff
  *-network
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       producto: Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 [Kilmer Peak]
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nombre lógico: wlp2s0
       versión: 5f
       serie: 64:80:99:24:8b:80
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-36-generic firmware=41.28.5.1 build 33926 ip=192.168.1.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       recursos: irq:36 memoria:f7e00000-f7e01fff
  *-network DESACTIVADO
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       id físico: 4
       nombre lógico: enx64d4da28f12d
       serie: 64:d4:da:28:f1:2d
       capacidades: ethernet physical
       configuración: driver=i2400m_usb firmware=i6050-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf link=no

-------------------------      
After suspend or reboot
-------------------------

sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       descripción: Interfaz inalámbrica
       producto: Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 [Kilmer Peak]
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       id físico: 0
       información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nombre lógico: wlp2s0
       versión: 5f
       serie: 64:80:99:24:8b:80
       anchura: 64 bits
       reloj: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuración: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-36-generic firmware=41.28.5.1 build 33926 ip=192.168.1.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       recursos: irq:36 memoria:f7e00000-f7e01fff
  *-network DESACTIVADO
       descripción: Ethernet interface
       id físico: 4
       nombre lógico: enx64d4da28f12d
       serie: 64:d4:da:28:f1:2d
       capacidades: ethernet physical
       configuración: driver=i2400m_usb firmware=i6050-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf link=no
```